# Postgresql parse pgScript variable to remove lines

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I am using pgScript and I have to pull information about the server that a database is residing on. I know I can get the IP Address and Ports but I need the hostname of the server. Currently I have:

```
declare @machineName;
declare @I;
set @I = 0;
create temp table foo (t text);
copy foo from '/etc/hosts';
set @machineName = 
    select * from foo;
print @machineName;
set @machineNameCount = select count(*) from foo;
```

I get back:

```
("127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4")
("::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6")
("xx.xx.x.xx  HOSTNAME")
```

I know I have three lines to work with, in this case, so I was going to run a while loop over @machineName using @machineNameCount and I just want to remove any line that has "127.0.0.1" or "::1" in it, but I can't figure out how to parse for those. If I can see if a line contains those I can then just remove that line. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I took a different approach to this then looking in the hosts file in /etc; I pulled the file /etc/sysconfig/network and looked specifically for the line that contained 'HOSTNAME'.

```
create temp table machineNameTable (col1 text);
copy machineNameTable from '/etc/sysconfig/network';
set @machineName = 
    select * from machineNameTable
    where col1 ilike '%HOSTNAME%';
print @machineName;
drop table machineNameTable;
```

which gives me back:

```
[PGSCRIPT ] ("HOSTNAME=SERVER_NAME")
```

Hope this can help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this bash command for drop lines that contains **127.0.0.1** or **::1** of output file

```
sed -i -e '/127\.0\.0\.1/d' -e '/::1/d' file
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to run a bash command from a pgscript. I have to do all this contained in a pgscript and I seem to be pretty limited in what parsing pgscript can do.